# ¿Hay alguna evidencia que relacione almohadas con los almohades?

Tags: etimología, transliteración, origen

En español, la palabra *almohada* es muy similar al nombre del Califato *Almohade* que reinó en partes de Iberia durante los siglos XII y XIII. He visto en foros mas informales la hipótesis de que los almohades habrían importado fábricas, cojines o incluso almohadas y que esto influenció el uso de "almohada" en referencia a su origen.

¿Existe evidencia alguna de esta relación entre almohades y almohadas? ¿O son palabras o raíces diferentes que se tradujeron con la misma ortografía en español?

Comment: Lo que siempre hemos aprendido en español es que las palabras que empiezan con al- son mayormente de origen árabe: almohada - alcohol - almíbar - aljibe - alcanfor - algodón, etc.

Comment: @Gustavson tienes razón almohada claramente viene del árabe, pero la pregunta concierne específicamente su relación con los almohades.

Comment: En Wikipedia encuentro lo siguiente: Su nombre proviene del árabe andalusí مخدة mujadda, con adición del artículo determinado al-, esto es: المخدة al-mujadda, que viene del árabe estándar mijadda: almohadón o cojín. La raíz de esta palabra es jadd (lado o mejilla), así que se relaciona semánticamente con el hecho de apoyar la mejilla o descansar de lado.

Comment: @Gustavson y Wikipedia también dice que Almohade viene del árabe "reconocer la unidad de Dios". En ese caso no estarían relacionadas las dos palabras. Pero no es lo que consigo en otros sitios, me gustaría conseguir una evidencia más clara o la versión de un experto.

Comment: Según el Diccionario Histórico de la Lengua Española, el origen de ambas palabras es bien diferente: https://www.rae.es/tdhle/almohade

Comment: Aunque a veces se confundan: https://www.lahistoriaespana.com/cojin-almohades/

Comment: No obstante, en algunos sitios (https://hammamalandalus.com/blog/origen-arabe-objetos-vida-cotidiana/) hacen algunas asociaciones un tanto forzadas: Un elemento tan importante para nuestro descanso como es la almohada, debe su procedencia etimológica al árabe. Dos son las teorías al respecto. Por un lado, hay quien dice que viene del  término árabe “al-mukhádda, que significa mejilla, por lo tanto la almohada sería donde reposa la mejilla.

Comment: Otros afirman  que es un invento de los almohades, para quienes la almohada  es la extensión de la cabeza. Los almohades soñaban la península Ibérica. En lengua beréber almohada sería  «la ensuavecida» o «la mullida», pero sugiere también «el sagrado destino».  Al dormirse, uno se encomienda a su almohada se dé el sitio donde Elí ha determinado que se vaya,  de modo que así empezará a gozar de su gloria.

Comment: ¿Por qué "alguna evidencia"? No corresponde a ninguna de las acepciones del [diccionario](https://dle.rae.es/evidencia?m=form). ¿No sería mejor decir "prueba" o "indicio"?

Comment: @Charo puedes hacer una nueva pregunta al respecto. Prueba es muy general, evidencia se utiliza aquí como referencia determinante. "Alguna evidencia" o "evidencia alguna" tiene que ver con cómo usar "alguno/alguna" más que con evidencia en sí misma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Si bien las etimologías para ambas palabras no son del todo claras, sería muy raro que ambas palabras provengan de la misma raíz. Las etimologías sugeridas son:

> [almohada](https://dle.rae.es/almohada?m=form) -> muẖádda (árabe hispánico) -> miẖadda ['mejilla'] (árabe clásico)

> [almohade](https://dle.rae.es/almohade) -> *almuwaḥḥád ['unificado'] (árabe hispánico) -> muwaḥḥid ['monoteísta'] (árabe clásico)

En este [sitio](https://blog.lengua-e.com/2010/etimologia-de-almohada/) se deja planteada una segunda hipótesis sobre el origen de 'almohada' de la palabra hebrea 'mahad' ['reclinar', en el sentido de que uno *reclina* la cabeza en la almohada], pero sin plantear una conexión entre las etimologías de los términos. Los primeros registros de 'almohada' [aparecieron un siglo después](https://www.elcastellano.org/palabra/almohada) de la retirada del Imperio de la Península.

Según lo que he encontrado y coinciden la mayoría de sitios, quienes las popularizaron (con un uso similar al de hoy) fueron griegos y romanos en la edad antigua, prohibiéndose su uso luego en la Edad Media excepto a la nobleza. No hay evidencia de que se hayan extendido al resto del mundo antes de la Revolución Industrial.

Lo que sí es muy probable es que el nombre provenga de cómo llamaban los almohades al objeto en discusión. Pero aunque las palabras se hayan deformado para quedar casi idénticas, la hipótesis sobre una raíz en común es muy difícil de sostener.

Answer (score 2):

Las etimologías de las dos palabras son perfectamente conocidas y totalmente diferentes. Los almohades son en árabe *al-muwaḥḥidūna* (الْمُوَحِّدُونَ), en singular *muwaḥḥid<sup>un</sup>* (مُوَحِّدٌ), que es un participio activo (o "agentivo", como lo llamaba el grandísimo arabista Federico Corriente) del verbo *waḥḥada* (وَحَّدَ), unificar. La palabra "almohada", por su parte, deriva de la palabra árabe, tanto clásica como de uso actual, *mijadda<sup>tun</sup>* (مِخَدَّةٌ), que en forma determinada sería *al-mijadda<sup>tu</sup>* (الْمِخَدَّةُ) y que, al parecer, en la forma dialectal andalusí se pronunciaba "al-mujadda", con variación en la primera vocal corta, algo habitual en los dialectos árabes.

En la mayor parte del léxico árabe, las palabras pueden analizarse a partir de raíces de tres consonantes complementadas por vocales (algo característico de todas las lenguas semíticas) y estas dos palabras tienen raíces totalmente diferentes: *w-ḥ-d* (و-ح-د), como el número "uno", en el caso del verbo "unificar" de los almohades; y *j-d-d* (خ-د-د), en el caso de la almohada. El parecido fonético en la evolución castellana es una mera coincidencia.

Answer (score -1):

Tanto la palabra "**almohada**" como "**almohade**", poseen procedencias distintas aunque utilizan palabras parecidas y cuyo sonido ha evolucionado en español de manera muy similar, de ahí la confusión.

De esta manera almohada y almohade utilizan por una parte el mismo articulo "*la, los*" (al), así "(la) al-mohada" "(los) al-mohades", la palabra "*mu o mo*" que llama a la idea de que algo que es "*mono*", "*como mono-teísta*", "*único*", "*unidad*", "*uno*" junto al concepto religioso "**Tawhid"** (unir) wahid o ahad que viene en la palabra  "al-mu**waḥḥidūn**" (al-mo-**hades**) que significa unir con uno o con lo único, "*uno en el sentido monoteísta de Dios*" y su confusión con otras posibles palabras candidatas que vienen en **almohada**  como oído, oreja أُذُن "**udhun**" (adan o adhān ), mejilla خدّ (khd) y cerebro o cabeza مخ (mukhkh). El fonema "*kh*" suena como la "*j*" en español.

Se cree que el nombre de "**almohada**" (مخدة *makhida* *almohadon*), proviene del árabe andalusí مخدة (makhadatun) , con adición del artículo determinado *al*- المخدة  (*al-mikhada / al-mujadda*). La raíz de esta palabra estaría compuesta por la palabra "*mu-mo*", en sentido de unidad como "mono", "uno" o "uno junto a" y de palabras como mejilla خدّ (*khd*), cerebro o cabeza مخ (*mukhkh*) o أُذُن 'udhun, (*adhān*), que significa "*oído*", "*oreja*"... y cuya raíz árabe *ʼḏn*, significa "oír", "escuchar", "llamar", verbo que se utiliza en la llamada a la oración de los musulmanes y que significarían aproximadamente "el uno junto a la mejilla" (al-mukhkh), "el uno junto a la cabeza o cerebro" (al-mukhadi) "el uno con la oreja" o "la unión junto a la oreja, pues quizás la relación de la **almohada** se halle en el modo en que el **almuédano** مُؤَذِّن (muʾadh·dhin), coloca ambas manos sobre sus oídos para recitar la llamada a la oración, asemejando a cuando uno se acuesta y pone la mano cerca o junto al oído, junto a la mejilla o junto a esa parte de la cabeza, a modo de vocifero o almuedanero (*obsérvese igualmente la semejanza de **almuédano** con la palabra almohada*). En España existe una expresión que aún se mantiene en la actualidad, que es "*planchar la oreja*" y que significa "*dormir*", así "*irse a planchar la oreja*" significa "*irse a dormir*".

Por otra parte el "**almohadísmo**" fue la interpretación radical de Ibn Tumart del concepto de la doctrina del "**tawḥid**" (توحيد‎) que literalmente significa "*unir*", y que atribuye el carácter de "*Unicidad*" a "*Allah*", por lo que se le describe como *Uno* y *Único*, sin compañeros ni pares en su esencia y atributos, por ello habitualmente se traduce como "*unidad o unidad con Dios*", y de donde los **almohades** obtienen su nombre "al-muwaḥḥidūn" (المُوَحِّدون), referido a ese "mono"- teísmo (de un solo Dios) en la religión árabe. Por tanto su nombre, "**Almohades**", al-muwaḥḥidūn ( المُوَحِّدون ), donde "mu" se refiere al aspecto "mono" o "único" de algo, mientras "waḥḥid" se refiere al sentido religioso de la doctrina "**tawḥid**", توحيد‎ (tawhidu), "*unir*", unión en el contexto de "*unidad*" referido a Dios, así significaría literalmente "*La mono-unión*", "*Solo el Único*" es decir, "La unión única de un solo Dios" pero no como he leído por ahí "*el que profesa la unión con Dios*", sino que la unión se refiere a la del propio Dios y por lo tanto "Los **Almohades**" (Al-Muwahhidun), se podría traducir como "**Los mono-teístas**".

Comment: El primer párrafo, correcto. Pero después parece que dejas volar la imaginación e inventas cosas. No existe en árabe ninguna palabra "mu o mo" con significado "uno" equiparable al prefijo "mono-". Las sílabas iniciales con "mu" son simplemente un mecanismo sintáctico normal en árabe para construir participios, como en muwaḥḥid, "el que unifica/profesa la unidad" y también muchos tipos de sustantivo, como el "nombre de instrumento" (اسم الآلة) del que la palabra mijadda, "almohada", es un caso particular.